# How does a party receiving frames under HTTP 2.0 know the order?

Tags: web-development, http

The frames are sent in multiplexed fashion and have a stream id. The receiver re arranges frames with the same stream id but what happens if an older frame arrives first?

Is there a concept of sequence number in http2.0 stream frames?

Comment: HTTP doesn't have any concept of frames.  That's taken care of at a lower layer which usually, but is not required to, support that concept.

Comment: @Blrfl: [RFC 7540 Section 4 is titled *HTTP Frames*](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#FramingLayer) and specifies the framing layer of HTTP/2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, HTTP/2 is only specified for transport on top of TCP, which is a connection-oriented, reliable protocol, IOW it guarantees that packets are never re-ordered, duplicated, or lost. As long as the sender sends the frames in the correct order, they will arrive in the correct order.

Likewise, HTTP/3 is essentially HTTP/2 adapted for transport over QUIC instead of TCP. QUIC again, is a connection-oriented, reliable protocol like TCP, even though it is based on UDP.

In other words: as long as frames are *sent* in the correct order, they *cannot* be received in the wrong order, so there is no need to have provisions in the spec for that.